# How can I uninstall an incompatible addon in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

There are two incompatible addons in my addons list that the *Uninstall* button is disabled for. They were working well in Firefox 3.5, but upon installing Firefox 3.6 they became incompatible.

The first one is **PC Sync 2 Synchronisation Extension**:

[image: PC Sync 2 Synchronisation Extension]

The second one is  **Firefox Synchronisation Extension**:

[image: Firefox Synchronisation Extension]

How can I uninstall them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some programs install *global add-ons* (available to all users of Firefox on your computer) for Firefox. Because these aren't local add-ons (installed by you for use on your Firefox profile), you can't uninstall them in the usual manner. Most global add-ons are installed either by copying the extension to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox** (or equivalent directory); or by making registry entries. Please read [this article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_Uninstall_Extensions) carefully as it provides details on how to remove global add-ons.

If your intention is to make these plugins work with FF3.6 (rather than removing them), you can [disable compatibility checking](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Updating_extensions#Completely_disabling_the_compatibility_check).

Comment: Thanks friend, If I disable `compatibility checking`, will Firefox work as well as before ?

Comment: If the plugins isn't too old (like 12 months or older), they should work fine. You can disable compatibility checking and try it out. If things don't work out, just set compatibility checking to "true" and restart Firefox; this will bring you back to default settings.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to edit the version range these extensions *claim* compatibility with.  This is assuming they really do work but that their compatible-version range hasn't been updated to include the latest Firefox version, but this is often the case.  The advantage is that compatibility checking remains enabled to check any new extensions you add later.

See the second tip in this article:
http://www.techpavan.com/2009/07/17/firefox-addon-not-working-compatibility-hack-firefox-addons/